# R will not let me change the color of the individual bars on a ggplot no matter what

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is my column of data

```
structure(list(summresolution = c("New supplier Found", "Supplier educated about DMEPOS\n", 
                                  "Unresolved", "Supplier educated about DMEPOS\n", 
                                  "Resolved by current supplier", 
                                  "Supplier educated about inquiry\n")))
```

I am creating a ggplot using this code:

```
sumrc<-ggplot(subset(longdata,!is.na(summresolution)),
              aes(x=summresolution))

sumrcbycount <- sumrc + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual("legend", 
                    values = c("New supplier Found" = "black", 
                               "Beneficiary Educated" = "orange", 
                               "Resolved by current supplier" = "blue",
                               "Unresolved"= "red"))

print(sumrcbycount)
```

I have scoured the web for the answer, because it seems like such a simple issue but no matter what I do the color just stays black.

Comment: your example doesn't work. Clear your workspace and try yourself.

Comment: What do you mean? Will all bars have one colour or each bar a different colour?

Comment: ok I have a really large dataset in here and I am just trying to show the 1 column of data Im building my chart off of. I am new to R and new to Stack so I'm not very good at providing the example data like you are supposed too.  The code that creates the chart is 100% right because it works in my console. why wont it change the colors tho?

Comment: I want each bar to have its own color

Comment: `sumrcbycount <- sumrc + geom_bar(stat = "count", fill = "lightgreen")` will work but i need each bar to be a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
library(ggplot2)
sumrc<-ggplot(subset(longdata,!is.na(summresolution)), 
              aes(x=summresolution, fill=summresolution))
sumrcbycount <- sumrc + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Supplier educated about inquiry\n" = "black", 
                                         "Supplier educated about DMEPOS\n" = "orange", 
                                         "Resolved by current supplier" = "blue",
                                         "New supplier Found" = "yellow")
                    )
print(sumrcbycount)
```

I added `fill` in your `aes` and then changed the `scale_fill_manual` too.

Out:

[image]